# Open Source customer review system in Django, or any other Python framework

Tags: django, open-source, comments, disqus, review

I want to implement an opinion or customer review system, kind of Disqus, or comments for models in Django, with some extra work on processing this reviews.

I have been googling and searching in github for hours, some platform for working with customer reviews, opinions or comments. 
Seems like there is a big controversy about comments native in Django. I have read many good, but many bad things so far.

I am wondering if some of you guys know something similar to Disqus but open source.

I am searching some open source platform, because there is a lot of work to do(in which actually I am working) based on processing the reviews and analyzing them and I wanted to cut off the time for developing from scratch the whole system for managing users and reviews, and focus on the text analytics part.

Any opinion is welcomed! 
bests,

Luchux.

Comment: At least you did your own research, first, so kudos for that, but this question is still not appropriate for StackOverflow. See: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask. FWIW, when looking for Django packages the best place to go is http://www.djangopackages.com/

Comment: Ok Chris, you are right. I think I will address the solution implementing something by myself, so I will post an appropriate question if I need help of this great community.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at askbot (disclaimer - I am co-founder and developer of the askbot project).

Askbot is a Q&A system like this site, only [open source](https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel) and more flexible and has better support of email. Our project is still work in progress but we are moving quite fast.

Comment: Btw, you can register a site at [askbot.com](http://askbot.com/) it's free to try out.

Comment: Thanks Evgeny. I have installed askbot and coded on it some time ago ;) Congratulations for that app! Anyway, in this moment I am searching for some customer opinions or reviews platform,  to be easily adapted to products models inside Django. If you think Askbot has some small functionality easy adaptable to what I need, let me know. 
The main idea is that users can have different opinion about products, and yep it can be seen as a Q&A system (but the latter seems a super set of what I need ;) 
Thanks for you help!